# How to avoid returning a zero

Tags: java, int, factorization

I have got the code working, it is a prime factorization method class and tester.  It prints out the code fine but I am forced to return a zero value, because the method is an Integer method.

```
public class FactorGenerator{
private int num;

public FactorGenerator(int numberToFactor){
    num = numberToFactor;
}
public int nextFactor(){
    for(int i = 2; i <= num;){
        if (num%i==0){
            num = num/i;
            System.out.println(i);
        }
        else{
            i++;
        }
    }
return 0;
}
public boolean hasMoreFactors(){
    for(int i = 1; i < num; i++){
        if(num % i == 0){
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
    }
}
```

And this is the tester I am using, which cannot be changed, and must stay the same:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

 public class FactorPrinter{
  public static void main(String [] args){

    Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Enter a number to Factor:");
    int numberToFactor = in.nextInt();

    System.out.println("You chose: "+numberToFactor+" to factor.");

    FactorGenerator fg = new FactorGenerator(numberToFactor);

    while (fg.hasMoreFactors())
        System.out.println(fg.nextFactor());
  }
 }
```

When I input 150, it prints 2,3,5,5,0
Is there anyway to remove the 0?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Don't *print* the factors in `nextFactor()`. *Return* them.

```
public int nextFactor() {
    for (int i = 2; ; i++) {
        if (num % i == 0) {
            num /= i;
            //System.out.println(i);
            return i;
        }
    }
}
```

The test `num % i == 0` is guaranteed to return true eventually, so if you remove the `i <= num` test from the `for` loop the compiler won't require you to add `return 0` at the end.

Comment: *facepalm*  Wow, thanks. I don't know why I completely neglected the i++ at first.  Also returning the i instead of printing it was much better.

Comment: Your original code with `i++` in an `else` is fine; you need that to handle duplicate factors properly. Moving it inside the `for` loop only works now because the loop is restarted every time you call `nextFactor()`.

Answer (score 2):

All required prints are done in `nextFactor`. So just don't print the return code. Change this:

```
System.out.println(fg.nextFactor());
```

by this:

```
fg.nextFactor();
```

That said, the `nextFactor` name is then ill-named. Even if it yields the result, the name suggests that it's a generator which should return each factor at each call, the memory effect being provided by the `num` member method. 
So doing what I'm advising works, but it may not be in the spirit of the problem. John's answer would be better if you have to examine/store the factors, not only print them.

Comment: The only problem is that for the class, we have to use the teacher's tester.  As silly as that may be it's required.

Comment: Then John's solution is the way to go.

Answer (score 0):

Your `hasMoreFactor()` method should have returned false by the time it has been invoked four times (and `nextFactor` returned 2, 3, 5, 5, respectively) and is invoked the fifth time.